# Floating menu with content divs

Tags: jquery, menu, navigation

Ok overall the effect I am trying to get is like this [web](http://nordkapp.fi/)
what I've been able to find so far and applied is from this [tutorial net tuts](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/creating-a-floating-html-menu-using-jquery-and-css/)
Now I changed the css so it shows horizontal but for some reason the menu is on top of the text and what I need is like the first site to show menu always on top but put content underneath.  Also it has a smooth scroll which i'm assuming it uses Jquery for it.  Well any pointers would be more than appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It might help if you post the CSS you have so far. My two cents? It looks like your elements aren't properly configured with the position property (or you have some funky HTML flow issues).

Try sketching out a "box model" of the desired outcome on paper first - this is the first thing designers do and it helps them visualize what they're building!

Comment: CSS is not really the issue i think it has to do more with the jquery part, to tell it it to go to the div put not on top.  The effect that I am looking for actually gmail has applied it aswell, if you notice when checking your inbox if u scroll down, the menu part stays on top. that's the effect i am trying to accomplish here.

Answer (score 0):

Ok figured it out..i guess well it works for now..I took the same theory for the tutorial, changed the css so it's horizontal, then on each div that it scrolls to I added a "subdiv" that has padding-top:60px and this way it shows the menu on top of the section and doesn't cut off that top part.  Thanks it did help mapping it out on paper, I tend to do things in my head and go straight to the programming :)